# ng-routing with complex UI in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

We are building an application with complicated UI. 
This is the sample view of a page in the application:

[image]

Left menu will contain the list of links for the corresponding pages in the right side.

We are using ng-router for building the application.

We took the whole page as one ng-view and include the left menu as single html template.
When clicking on the links, we will replace the right side tab content by ng-include.

Inside each right side content, we have sub tabs. When clicking on sub tab, we will replace the content of sub tab.

In Left menu template controller we have few ajax calls. When loading the content of the sub tab in right side, templates are not reloaded by the angular and is cached by the angular.  But the ajax calls are reloaded again.

It should not reload the ajax calls inside the left menu when changing the content of sub tab in the right content.

Somebody might have faced this issue. Please suggest me to proceed further.

Comment: Did you found the solution? I have similar application, and ngRouter is not very suitable for this.

Comment: Finally we have concluded to use ui-router only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should check the `ui-router` project from the **angular-ui** team.

You will find their routing and the possibility to have nested views, named views and parameters super helpful with a complex design like yours.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: ui-router is not a native angular code. Its a third party plugin. So we are afraid to use that. Also ng-view will be providing multi view and fix the issues related to that in next version.

Comment: Angular purposefully extracted it's routing component from the core so people can choose other routing solutions.
I know it's not native Angular, but given the community angular-ui has and the developers who are working on it full-time, it is a very reliable option to me.

Comment: Also, if you're only going to use Angular code, you will have to implement a lot of existing code again. Which will be, of course, prone to errors on your behalf...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to ui-router:

- http://dotjem.github.io/angular-routing/
- http://angular-route-segment.com/

Without diving into pros and cons.

Comment: ui-router is not a native angular code. Its a third party plugin. So we are afraid to use that. Also ng-view will be providing multi view and fix the issues related to that in next version.

Comment: That is a silly notion, why do you then dare to use angular?... jquery?... Surely the safe bet must be to just use the PURE api provided by the browser and not use ANY 3rd party libraries... like jQuery or Angular. (Sarcasm may occur)